# How to map a function call in MySQL select for a specific table cell?

Tags: mysql

I had 2 tables:

```
   workers: id, user_id, group_id, name, ...
   worker_groups: id, name, ...
```

The "group_id" is the relation with worker_groups. This was a fixed relation. Now, my task is, to change the group_id in specific dates. So, i made a 3rd table:

```
   relation: id, w_id, wg_id, start_date
```

It's a huge project, and i need a solution to return the group_id for the desired worker on current days. My old query:

```
   SELECT id, name, group_id FROM workers 
   WHERE  user_id = 1;
```

I don't want to change my old query, is there any solution, to map "group_id" cell with a query/function/procedure or view to return the present "group_id" from the relation table? Or the only solution is to edit my query and make the function call from it?

**SOLUTION**

The desired resolution was achieved by renaming the old table, and creating a view with the old table name. I must change the table name in edit/add functions, but at least this could be done quickly

Comment: Why don't you want to change the query? That makes the most sense and has the least chance of convoluted side effect

Comment: You could rename the `workers` table, and then create a view named `workers` that contains the mapping using the new table name.

Comment: Because it's a huge project, with many modules, it would be more effective if it could be done from MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired resolution was achieved by renaming the old table, and creating a view with the old table name. I must change the table name in edit/add functions, but at least this could be done quickly